# understanding of an application of the Zorn's lemma

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm reading a proof of the extension theorem of positive functionals:

[image]

I can see by Zorn's lemma that a maximal element $(Z,\varphi)$ exists in $F$. But I don't understand why one can further assume that
$$
(Y,\varphi_0)\leq (Z,\varphi),
$$
since I can't see why $(Z,\varphi)$ and $(Y,\varphi_0)$ are necessarily comparable. Could anyone give me a hand here?

Comment: You consider the subfamily $F' = \{(Z,\varphi) \in F : (Y,\varphi_0) \leq (Z,\varphi)\}$. That is inductive too.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Do you mean that one should apply Zorn's lemma in $F'$ instead of $F$, which means the quoted proof is not strictly correct?

Comment: Well, they might use a form of Zorn's lemma that states "If $(X,\leq)$ is a nonempty inductively ordered set, then for every $x\in X$ there is a maximal element $m$ of $X$ with $x \leq m$". Then the proof is correct. If their version of Zorn's lemma is the usual one that states only existence of maximal elements, their proof is not strictly correct.

Comment: @DanielFischer:  Fair enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of an answer, I would like to repeat @Daniel Fishcher's comment here:

> They might use a form of Zorn's lemma that states "If $(X,≤)$ is a nonempty inductively ordered set, then for every $x∈X$ there is a maximal element $m$ of $X$ with $x≤m$". Then the proof is correct. If their version of Zorn's lemma is the usual one that states only existence of maximal elements, their proof is not strictly correct.